# Is it possible to hire a phd student or postdoc by hours?

Tags: thesis, postdocs, job, salary

I am working on small projects in machine learning field at my spare time. I love to research on the main ideas and concepts. However, I won't have much time on implementing it. Since the field requires special abilities, I feel it would be better to hire a phd student or postdoc.

When I search online, even part-time postdoc jobs offer around 50k annually. Since my projects are not that big and I do not have much money, would it be possible to hire a phd or postdoc by working hours for the projects ?

Comment: _part-time postdoc jobs offer around 50k annually_ In which country? For how many hours?

Comment: The last part of the question is a shopping question asking for recommendations, and those are not received very well here. Removing the last paragraph would improve the question.

Comment: Thanks! :) any idea about where might be suitable for the last part of the question ? Oops ! Sorry~Is this another shopping question?

Comment: Universities hire hourly employees and contractors all the time.  If you are not hiring using university funds, your question is off-topic.

Comment: I suggest you change the mindset. Don't hire, collaborate. It should be much easier to find an academic collaborator (standard practice in academia) than someone willing to enter an hourly contract. Of course, your project has to be interesting.

Comment: Do you have to use university funds to hire freelancers ? Would it be possible that one hires those collaborators(e.g. Phd students, Postdocs) as freelancers without using university funds and listed them co-authors if there is any publication ?

Comment: 50k in which currency???

Comment: @Sweetie AnonymousPhysicist's point is that if you aren't a university and asking how to hire people, you're talking about something outside of academia. You could maybe ask about restrictions that academics would face while doing outside work, but "how do I hire someone?" in a non-academic context isn't on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would it be possible to hire a phd or postdoc by working hours for the projects ?

Yes, but, can you afford one? You've highlighted the cost of a *part-time postdoc [at] around 50k annually* and noted *[you] do not have much money*.

> does anyone have rough idea about the price range/hour?

Compute the hourly postdoc rate (from the above salary) and multiply it by some factor (probably greater than two). (The hourly rate is non-trivial to compute, given that many postdocs work more than their contractual hours.)

Comment: If the work isn't going to lead to a publication then most people are going to want a lot of money.

Comment: @StrongBad That's why _multiply [hourly postdoc rate] by some factor (probably greater than two)_